# How to Add a new Tab in Product View Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, blocks

I want to add a new tab in the product view page similar to Details.

[image]

> I have tried adding a file 'catalog_product_view.xml' at the location
>   "app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/" and added the below
>   code

```
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">            
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description.extra" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom</argument>
                    </arguments>            
                 </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body> 
   </page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this useful for you..

1. Create one custom theme Refernece:

   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

   https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/
2. create  catalog_product_view.xml file  in your custom theme  **/app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**
3. Then, add below code to **catalog_product_view.xml**

   ```
       <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
           <body>
                <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">            
                   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.info.description.extra" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                       <arguments>
                           <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom</argument>
                       </arguments>            
                    </block>
               </referenceBlock>
           </body> 
       </page>
   ```

   4. Remove var/*

      rm -rf var/*

Now, check Its worked for me..

**Note:** You can also add this code luma theme /app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml  its work, But this way is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep your above xml file at below location inside your custom theme catalog folder.

`app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout`

Your xml code is correct given in questions just you have to keep xml file in above mentioned location.

Run command

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Remove var folder and check.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your answer. I have tried placing the xml file "catalog_product_view.xml" at the location "app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Catalog\layout\" but still it did not work. I have run the command "php bin/magento cache:clean" and removed var folder as suggested. Is there any other thing am I missing?

Comment: You have to create your custom theme and keep inside xml file

Comment: You cant keep inside Magento/luma folder

Comment: But I am still using the same luma theme. Do i need to create a new one set that as the store theme?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create your own theme and set your theme from admin panel and after set your theme.

Create your theme is used when you have to override your core templates and layout file.

You can get many references for create custom theme in magento 2.

run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command

Comment: Have you working for you above suggestions?